# How can I write while loop in order to make it stop when 2 variables got certain values? (Python)

Tags: python

I have the following code (in Python):

```
while i != 0 and j != 0:
  possibAct, posX, posY = possibleActions(i, j)
  i, j = constructValueFunction_GetOptimalAction(possibAct, posX, posY)
  possibAct, i, j = possibleActions(i, j)
```

Seems like it stops when only one (i or j) gets to 0, but what I want is to make it stop only when both are 0. What am I missing?

Comment: Is ```i``` or ```j``` always decreased by 1 after ```while``` block finished?

Comment: As an aside, do you really need the second call to `possibleActions` at the bottom of the loop?

Comment: `while (i+j)!=0`

Answer (score 1):

You can give or like this:

```
while i!=0 or j!=0:
   (some code)
```

*when i is 0 ,j may not be 0 so it waits for j to become 0*

Answer (score 0):

With your current code, loop will break when any of i,j gets 0 as i!=0 and j!=0 becomes False. You need something like the following, in order to stop the loop only if both i and j become 0:

```
while not (i == 0 and j == 0):
  possibAct, posX, posY = possibleActions(i, j)
  i, j = constructValueFunction_GetOptimalAction(possibAct, posX, posY)
  possibAct, i, j = possibleActions(i, j)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace `and` with `or`